# Spring Scheduler Disallow Concurrent Alternative

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

When scheduling a task in Quartz, you have the ability to set misfires and rescheduling. This could be used in the example scenario whereby there is a job that runs every 30 mins, and potentially there could be a backlog and and the job would execute for longer than 30 mins. To prevent the same job running twice you could use the `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`. Once complete the job would then execute the second instance that is queued by using `simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionNowWithExistingCount()`.

Now in Spring Scheduler there doesn't appear to be this fine grained ability, with just the `fixed-rate` and `fixed-delay` options to schedule it every 30 mins or wait 30 mins after the previous job completed. Without using the hammer route of restricting to a single thread, as I want to increase the thread count for other batch jobs to run concurrently, what would be the best method of recreating the Quartz behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like with the basic Spring Scheduler there isn't such a mechanism. To do this either use the Spring Quartz Scheduler, or Quartz directly.